# ionic keyboard moves content upwards

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm a beginner on ionic framework. Just doing markup for the app not developing the whole application.

on focusing field the keyboard opens and pushed ion-footer upwards i have set position and bottom values but none of them is working.

Here is the code of the page.

```xml
<ion-pane class="login">
      <ion-content class="has-footer" scroll="false">
          <div class="row topgap">
              <div class="col-80 col-offset-10">                  
                  <div class="fixWidthContainer">
                      <h2 class="text-center">Welcome to Givi</h2>
                      <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name" />
                      <input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
                      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                      <br />
                      <button class="button button-full LoginButton">Sign up</button>
                      <button class="button button-full LoginButton facebook">Sign up using Facebook</button>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </ion-content>

      <ion-footer-bar class="transparentfooter">
          <button href="#" class="button footercustombutton">Login</button>
      </ion-footer-bar>
  </ion-pane>
```

Also when the keyboard opens the background value is cover is also adjust itself and get smaller. What to do with this...

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

check this value if its false change it to true

```
  <preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />
```